# Nothing works anymore after building project in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was going to build my project when i noticed i didn't put an icon, 
and since i couldn't access the icon value of the original form because i used a theme i C+X the container and access it from the grey form, change it, C+V the container, built the project.
Nothing changed, all the name of the buttons and stuff are the same, but i feel like nothing is connected to the code anymore, i don't know what happened, i just recently got re-interested into coding, and i have no idea what to do, i tried some things but nothing worked, so here i am, desperate (i spent 3 days on this, i'm REALLY starting from bottom)

link to the project: http://www.mediafire.com/file/2zrbe32lzpx2qhz/SchedulerProjectVBNET.rar

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have lost all the `Handles` clauses off your event handlers.  As an example, if you add a `Button` to your form and double-click it, you will get a `Click` event handler like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

Note the `Handles` clause at the end, which is what connects the code to the event of the control.  If you cut that `Button` from your form to the Clipboard then it no longer exists as part of the form, so that `Handles` clause will be automatically removed.  If you paste the `Button` back onto the form, the `Handles` clause is not restored, so the method no longer handles the event.

If that's what has happened - which you can easily check just by looking at the code - then you need to restore all those `Handles` clauses.  You can do that manually, i.e. write them all yourself in the code window, or you can have the designer regenerate them for you.  To do the latter, select a control in the designer, open the Properties window, click the Events button, select the desired event and then select the appropriate method from the drop-down list.

Note that you can also double-click an event there to generate a new event handler, which can be useful for handling events other than the default event.  You can generate a handler for the default event simply by double-clicking the control.

Comment: Thank you lots ! i tried to add handles manually yesterday and i didn't work so i thought it was something else, i tried to do it with the designer and it worked !